# EditControl MFC: Anyway to prevent keyboard input but still remain ability to right click and choose copy/paste

Tags: c++11, mfc, paste, editcontrol

I already have set EditControl in MFC to true, It lock user's keyboard input, but i still need ability to cut/copy/paste. Is there anyway to just prevent user input but still functioning copy/paste. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can disable it. This will prevent any modifications, but will allow the copy operation. As the paste operation will be disabled too, you must enable it, or implement it yourself. Otherwise, you will have to process keyboard input (`WM_CHAR` etc).

Comment: Sir can you be more specific in a way to proccess keyboard input . Thanks you

Comment: When you say cut and paste, you DO want them to DELETE or CHANGE the edit control (via the CUT and via the PASTE), just not be able to CHANGE it via a character typing?  Also, do you expect Ctrl+X , Ctrl+C or Ctrl+V to  also work in addition to the context menu cut/copy/paste mechanism?  Normally, a read-only edit control will support COPY, but not CUT/PASTE.

Comment: Yeah sorry for my bad english sir. My point is not get the edit control able to be change via character typing. I expect function copy/paste to be worked also the hotkey for that mechanism.